# How structure a realm database without instantiating variables with null in one-to-one mapping?

Tags: java, android, realm

How would I structure my Realm database if the user had an option to input one of 4 fields: a,b,c,d.

Currently I've created one RealmObject model class with all of the getters and setters in one class, so if a user adds to c, the output looks like this:

```
[modelClassName = [{a:null},{b:null},{c:6664},{d:null}]]
```

Is this the best way to go about it? Or should I be creating a model class for each variable? The latter seems like an overkill.

Comment: How about an enum?

Comment: `[modelClassName = [{a:null},{b:null},{c:6664},{d:null}]]` this sounds fine to me, but you should keep track of which one had its value set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my article [Designing the Schema of Realm effectively](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.31toiq8jr), you can store the fields in one "table", and store an additional *discriminator* field that determines which field is currently valid to read from.

So in your case,

```
public class Something extends RealmObject {
    public static final String TYPE_A = "a";
    public static final String TYPE_B = "b";
    public static final String TYPE_C = "c";
    public static final String TYPE_D = "d";

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;

    @Index
    private String discriminator;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = null;
        this.c = null;
        this.d = null;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_A;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.a = null;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = null;
        this.d = null;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_B;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.a = null;
        this.b = null;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = null;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_C;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.a = null;
        this.b = null;
        this.c = null;
        this.d = d;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_D;
    }
}
```

Or something like that. Additional validation or some unified `getValue()` method can be added, the types can be represented by an `enum` instead (and the enum's `name()` could be stored in the Realm), etc.

In fact, if you want, you can even just merge all `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` fields into 1 field called `value, and also keep the discriminator.

```
public class Something extends RealmObject {
    public static final String TYPE_A = "a";
    public static final String TYPE_B = "b";
    public static final String TYPE_C = "c";
    public static final String TYPE_D = "d";

    @Index
    private String discriminator;

    private String value;

    // getters, setters

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.value = a;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_A;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.value = b;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_B;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.value = c;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_C;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.value = d;
        this.discriminator = TYPE_D;
    }
}
```

It's up to you, really.

---

This answer is applicable for Realm 0.88.0+